# Water damage on paint beneath sink: is this a water leak?

Tags: plumbing, leak, water-damage

I recently installed a DIY sink as a temporary solution while waiting for a new bathroom cabinet and sink to arrive.

Over the course of the past few weeks I've been noticing strange bubbles appearing on the paint beneath the sink, next to the sewer connection and water outlets.

The problem is progressively getting worse, but I can't figure out what the source of it is. I called a plumber and he said it's nothing to worry about, and probably due to the wall being wet when it got painted. However, the problem got worse since then.

All of the paint bubbles you can see in the pictures actually appeared after the plumber came last time, so it's an ongoing problem.

The only causes I can think of are:

- There's a leak in one of the water outlets or in the drain pipe. If the leak is in the drain pipe, it wouldn't explain why bubbles are showing above and to the side of it.
- The room gets damp when I take showers. Some of the humidity might be depositing where the paint got damaged and causing more bubbles. Hard to explain how the bubbles got started in the first place however.
- The paint got laid on a wet wall. This explanation doesn't seem to hold considering it's been a month since I painted and the problem is still getting worse.

Here are some photos showing the issue. The areas where the paint has come off completely are due to me scratching that off with my finger when I first discovered the issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how we're going to answer that for you, being way over here. How often does water get splashed on the wall?

Comment: `is this ...?` is a question that asks for 100% certainty ... you need to hire someone that can actually examine the plumbing

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that this is not easy to answer at a distance. I was curious if these marks I'm seeing are something that's commonly recognized as caused by a leak or other issues.
In terms of water coming in contact with the wall, I'd say it can happen once or twice a week, or more frequently if we count that the room gets a bit steamy when I shower.

Comment: If paint was not put on correctly or surface not prepared, you see problems with it sooner or later.  Most paint can withstand some water/moisture being on it for a little time, not soaking in bathtub for a few days.   Is there water pipes behind/in wall that could be leaking?

Comment: Are those little lumps thin bubbles of paint that can be (reasonably) easily scraped off, or are they blobs of thick paint from a poorly done paint job? i.e., if you scrape at one with a fingernail, will it flake off or is it solid? From way over here, the ones under the supply escutcheon, in particular, look like thick blobs of paint, not bubbles.

Comment: @FreeMan they are empty bubbles that can be scraped off. More and more have been appearing over time, and it's been a while since the walls got painted.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe it is a water leak, as you would start seeing water stains underneath the area where the paint is peeling.

The reason for the paint blistering are the reasons you stated in your description.

> Plumber - wall being wet when it got painted. However, the problem got
> worse since then.

Painting while the surface is wet-damp would have prevented the paint from properly adhering to the wall.  Pain will continue to peel.

> The room gets damp when I take showers. Some of the humidity might be
> depositing where the paint got damaged and causing more bubbles. Hard
> to explain how the bubbles got started in the first place.

Moisture is penetrating through the paint and continues to lift the paint from the substrate.

To properly paint the area:

1. Remove the existing paint.
2. Apply primer when the area is dry.
3. Apply paint recommended for damp area.
4. (Optional) Apply a seal coat over the paint

Comment: Step 5: Install a proper bathroom vent fan to draw the hot humid air out as quickly as possible to minimize the issue in the future .